# SetQueryTimeout(int) jdbc3

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to establish a connection with Postgres DB.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM procesar(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setQueryTimeout(TIMEOUT);
```

But I have the following error: 
Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.

Aparently, it's a driver issue. I use JDBC3. 
My question is if there is another way to set timeout for db query? I cannot update the driver.

Comment: The 'other way' is to update the driver. The one you're using is from before 2007. Don't waste any more time on workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

yes, by running following query:

```
set [LOCAL] statement_timeout = '1s';
```

LOCAL means that this setting will be applied only inside transaction, otherwise you need to reset it after query is done.